# Change Languages information for app on App Store

Tags: ios, app-store

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkxuW.png My app is in two languages, English and Dutch. On app store it shows only English in Languages information. How do I change that.? Please see the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

[image: AppStoreConnect localization]

Check if you have localized your app also on App Store Connect.

The languages in the description of your app on the Apple App Store reflects the localizations you create on App Store Connect.